# Histogram list returning bin centers and count numbers rather than bin domain points

Tags: histograms

Is there a native Mathematica function, similar to `HistogramList[...]` which will return a list of bin centres and associated counts, rather than the bin domains. I guess it is probably a quick thing to write a custum function based on `HistogramList[...]` but if there is already a native function for this, then that would be great.

Comment: Why not use the second argument of HistogramList and specify exactly which bins you want?

Comment: @bills Because I don't always know that depending on my data type, I specify the number of bins either by some $n^{1/3}$ rule or some of the other histogram bin number algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, instead of:

```
list = HistogramList[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100]]
{{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {20, 17, 14, 27, 22}}
```

you want:

```
{MovingAverage[list[[1]], 2], list[[2]]}
{{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {23, 24, 25, 17, 11}}
```

or maybe you would prefer:

```
Thread[{MovingAverage[list[[1]], 2], list[[2]]}]
{{1, 23}, {3, 24}, {5, 25}, {7, 17}, {9, 11}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more fragile approach but quicker if one can assume a common binwidth:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
list = HistogramList[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100]]
(* {{0,2,4,6,8,10},{20,16,27,28,9}} *)

binwidth = list[[1, 2]] - list[[1, 1]];
{list[[1, Range[Length[list[[1]]] - 1]]] + binwidth/2, list[[2]]}
(* {{1,3,5,7,9},{20,16,27,28,9}} *)
```

But any additional speed is probably minuscule compared to getting the histogram counts in the first place.